# Get index of item in N- level nested listview c# UWP

Tags: c#, listview, recursion, uwp

I have a nested listview with variable depth. I do not know max depth since this listview will be populated by user (drag and drop) and it can have N- levels. I can assign a unique ID to each object in the collection to help with search. User can drop objects at any of N levels. Itemssource is an observable collection and each Object/item has two additional collections (displayed in listviews, e.g. children collection, friend collection).
When a user drops an object inside a nested collection (e.g. depth=3), i need to find the index 1) in the depth 3 collection, 2) parent index in depth=2, 3) grand parent index in depth=1 etc.
So that i can add this dropped item at correct location inside my Observable collection (itemsSource).

e.g. Items[X].ChildItems[Y].Add(draggedItem)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So ,what's your real problem? can't determine if  current level is depth 3?

Comment: real problem is to be able to find exact location inside the collection where item is dropped.. i used visualtree helper and now i know the indexes inside collection. i.e. if a user drops an object, i know it is in index 3, then in index 2 in nested collection, however, i am not sure how to write code without pointers to reach N level nested collection. since depth can vary, i cant write a function like collection[i].nestedCollection[y].

Comment: Ok, I got it, we suggest you view UWP treeview [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/1ecd85c908a8a1cb9a8201e548f58db379801e69/XamlControlsGallery/ControlPages/TreeViewPage.xaml.cs).

Comment: i tried treeview sample, didn't like its aesthetics and animation. i think listview is better..now i know the information, i think it is just a matter of writing recursive function. i have access to collection that is itemssource and indexes of each level. can u help with function to add an item if i give u collection and indexes. e.g. drop item at index 5 -> index 3-> index 7. Next drop may have different depth.

Comment: I mean, you could refer to ExplorerItem to build your own class, and using recursive to find the  level depth